# Regular Expression that Validates Decimal (18,3)

Tags: regex, validation

I need a regular expression that can validate `Decimal (18,3)`, meaning a precision of 18, and a scale of 3.

It would need to pass the following criteria:

- Max number of digits before comma is `15`
- Max number of digits after the comma is `3`

**Valid Examples**:

```
123456789.123
123456789123456.12
12345.1
123456789123456
```

**Not Valid Examples**:

```
1234567891234567
123.1234
1.12345
.1234
```

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 4):

First of all, the character `.` is called a dot, or period, or full stop, or decimal point, while a comma is the character: `,`.

Second, you can designate a digit in regex in a character class: `[0-9]` means any digit between 0 to 9.

A dot in regex will match any character, so you need to escape it by means of a backslash (or putting it in a character class).

Remember though that the elements in the same character class can be in any order, so that if you want to get something having digits and a dot and use `[0-9.]` it will match any digit, or a dot.

Now, you will need finite quantifiers for your task, which are designated by braces in the form of `{m,n}` where `m` is the minimum and `n` the maximum. If you now use... `[0-9.]{1,15}` it would mean the character class `[0-9.]` repeated 1 up to 15 times.

But if you use `[0-9.]{1,15}`, it will also match `......` or `1234` (remember I said earlier that the order did not matter.

So, applying all this, you get the regex:

```
[0-9]{1,15}\.[0-9]{1,3}
```

Now, since you are doing a validation, you will need anchors to specify that the regex should test the whole string (instead of simply finding a match).

```
^[0-9]{1,15}\.[0-9]{1,3}$
```

Last, since you can have optional decimals, you will have to use a group and the quantifier `?` which means 0 or 1:

```
^[0-9]{1,15}(?:\.[0-9]{1,3})?$
```

In your code, you will create the regex a bit like this:

```
string myString = "123456789.123";
var regexp = new Regex(@"^[0-9]{1,15}(?:\.[0-9]{1,3})?$");
var setMatches = regexp.Matches(myString);
foreach (Match match in setMatches)
{
    Console.WriteLine(match.Groups[0].Value);
}
```

This will output the decimal if it passed the regex.

Or something like this:

```
string myString = "123456789.123";
Match match = Regex.Match(myString, @"^[0-9]{1,15}(?:\.[0-9]{1,3})?$");
if (match.Success)
{
    Console.WriteLine(match.Groups[0].Value);
}
```

Comment: thanks a lot [0-9]{1,15}\.[0-9]{1,3} is working fine but i have to enter 3 digits after DOT , can i make it optional to take the digits after dot ?

Comment: @user2828076 Oh, right, sure. I actually missed that part ^^; I'll add it to my answer in a bit

Comment: @user2828076 Done, I've edited that part in my answer.

Answer (score 1):

This regex should work for you:

```
/^\d{1,15}(\.\d{1,3})?$/
```

In Java:

```
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("^\\d{1,15}(\\.\\d{1,3})?$");
```

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
  String str="Your input";
    Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("^\\d{1,15}($|(\\.\\d{1,3}$))");
    Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(str);
    while (matcher.find()) {
        System.output.Println(matcher.group());
    }
```

in c# try this

```
    MatchCollection mc = Regex.Matches("your text", "^\d{1,15}($|(\.\d{1,3}$))");
             foreach (Match m in mc)
             {
                Console.WriteLine(m);
            }
```

Comment: try now, i made some changes, this one will wrk,change 15 to 18 if need max 18 digits before .

Comment: if you have notepad++ , give you test cases and try this regex in find " ^\d{1,15}($|(\.\d{1,3}$)) " without quotes, in java you have to give escape backslashs

Comment: i am using csharp  and its not even accepting normal numbers like 4 or 452